# Update remote server folder permissions from localhost

Tags: php, permissions

```
<?php

$source_dir = "pimg";

$move1 = "1.png";
$target1 = "apple/boy/cat/d'!og";

$move2 = "2.png";
$target2 = "a/b";

if($moved = move_image($move1,$source_dir,$target1) ) {

    echo "<br> moved image = ".$moved;
}

if($moved = move_image($move2,$source_dir,$target2) ) {

    echo "<br> moved image = ".$moved;
}

function move_image($image, $source_dir, $target_dir) {

    $target_dir_arr = explode('/',$target_dir);

    $base_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

    $path = $base_dir;

    foreach($target_dir_arr as $value) {

        if(file_exists($path.'/'.$value)) {

            $path.='/'.$value;

            //echo "<br>".$path." exist";

        }
        else {

            //echo "<br>".$path." does not exist. ";

            if(mkdir($path.'/'.$value)) {

                //echo " $value created under $path ";

                $path.='/'.$value;

            }
            else {

                echo " $value can not create under $path ";

                return;
            }            
        }
    }

    // move image ///////////////////////////////////

    if(!empty($path)) {

        if(file_exists($source_dir.'/'.$image)) {

            if(copy($source_dir.'/'.$image, $path.'/'.$image)) {

                //echo "<br>$image moved under $path";  

                unlink($source_dir.'/'.$image);

                return $path.'/'.$image;

            }
            else {

                echo "<br>$image move failed under $path";  

                return; 
            }
        }
        else {

            echo "<br> source file $source_dir/$image does not exists. ";               
            return ;
        }
    }   
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use [`chmod()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php)?

```
<?php
// Read and write for owner, nothing for everybody else
chmod("/somedir/somefile", 0600);

// Read and write for owner, read for everybody else
chmod("/somedir/somefile", 0644);

// Everything for owner, read and execute for others
chmod("/somedir/somefile", 0755);

// Everything for owner, read and execute for owner's group
chmod("/somedir/somefile", 0750);
?>
```